# Can't reset global mark in vim

Tags: vim

I have a global mark `A` set to point to file `foo.txt`. Now I want to re-set it to point to `foo.org` instead...but I can't seem to. Vim still takes me to `foo.txt`, even after a restart. Looking at my `.viminfo`, I see that it's still got the old mark saved:

```
'A  1  0  ~/foo.txt
```

Even if I edit this file manually to point to `foo.org`, it just gets reset...my changes don't take. What's going on?

Comment: Strange problem ... do you mean you do `:marks A`, get `~/foo.txt`, then do `mA` in some random file, and then `:marks A` still returns `~/foo.txt`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After setting the mark, did you `:wviminfo` (e.g. write the viminfo file?) Was there possibly another Vim session open, that was quit after the one, in which you set the global mark? In that case, the second vim would probably overwrite the global mark again.

I think, some of the latest 7.3 patches changed how writing the viminfo file happened and how old data was being merged, which might have caused a regression.

In any case, explicitly writing the viminfo file (using `:wviminfo`) should work, if not, please write a detailled description of what you did and what you expect to the developers list (vim_dev@googlegroups.com).

Answer (score 0):

Set a global mark by using an uppercase letter. Like so:

```
mA
```

You may also want to check your `'viminfo'` settings via `:verbose set viminfo?`. You want to make sure you don not have `f0` in there.

For more information see:

```
:h mark
:h 'viminfo'
:h viminfo-file-marks
```

Comment: Yup, this is what I'm trying to do. It doesn't work (see my question for details).